# Two identical programs have different results. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

SO recently I learned to read files and use lists to grab specific information form them. Today, as a warm up i tried to rebuild the old program but for some reason i could not get the correct result. I copied and pasted the old program I made and still got the correct result. I was wondering if someone could tell me what the difference was because at this point I've literally copied my original program and still can get the correct result.

In correct result

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"
try:
    fh = open(fname)
except:
    print('File could not be opened',fname)
    quit()
count = 0
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.strip()
    lst = line.split()
    if not len(line) > 3: continue
    elif not line.startswith('From'): continue
    print(lst[1])
    count = count + 1

print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

Correct result:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"
try:
    fh = open(fname)
except:
    print('Could not open file',fname)
    quit()
count = 0
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.strip()
    lst = line.split()
    if not len(lst) > 3: continue
    elif not line.startswith('From'): continue
    print(lst[1])
    count = count + 1

print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

the result that it's supposed to give me is a count of 27 and 27 corresponding e-mail addresses. Here is the text file in question. [mbox-short](https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt)
I am using pycharm IDE

Comment: diffchecker.com

Answer (score 2):

In the first one you are checking the length of "line" (`if not len(line) > 3: continue`), but in the second one you are checking the length of "lst" (`if not len(lst) > 3: continue`). That's probably your problem.

Comment: Baw... you spoon feeder :-P

Comment: I cannot believe i didnt  catch that. thank you so much

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `if lst[0] != 'From': continue`?

Comment: `line.startswith('From')` matches both `From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008` and `From: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za`, which is why it gets a double count.

Comment: @barmar i haven't learned that yet (literally like a week into learning python) ill try that thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is between:

```
line = line.strip()
if not len(line) > 3: continue
```

and

```
lst = line.split()
if not len(lst) > 3: continue
```

You are comparing the length of characters in a line to a space separated list

```
test = "this is a line in a document."
list_example = test.split()
string_example = test.strip()

print(list_example)
print(len(list_example))
```

output:

```
['this', 'is', 'a', 'line', 'in', 'a', 'document.']
7
```

Compared to string:

```
print(string_example)
print(len(string_example))
```

output:

```
this is a line in a document.
29
```